# Django Mongoengine EmbeddedDocument query issue

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

my model is about a list of top movies

```
class Movie(Document):
    title = StringField()
      ...
    ranks = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Rank'))

class Rank(EmbeddedDocument):     
    rank = IntField()
    imdb_rating = FloatField()
    date = StringField(required=True)
```

How can I write a query to get only the movies have Rank record in today?

Comment: What I think Darin is suggesting is, good Stackoverflow etiquette suggests that some of your previous questions might need an accepted answer by now.  Correct me if I'm wrong Darin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise using a `datetime` object for date rather than a string as it seems more explicit.  Either way you can easily find all `Movie` documents with a rank that has a `date` matching today like so:

```
Movie.objects(ranks__date__gte=datetime.today().date())  # using DateTimeField
```

or

```
Movie.objects(ranks__date="16/04/2012")  # using StringField
```

Comment: It works! But how can I iterate the result in django template to get every movie's rank in today?..

Comment: Well MongoDB querying returns documents.  An if statement can loop through the ranks that match.